# Scheduling time specific operations with threads

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduling

In a multithreaded program with a single cpu, when we say a specific thread to do something let's say every 10 seconds, how can we assure that this thread will definitely run in(get the chance to run) exactly 10 seconds after the previous time it was executed?

In order for this thread to run in exactly 10 seconds, the OS has to interrupt any thread which was running at that particular time. As I know we do not have complete control over who gets to run at a particular time.

When we do time specific operations is all that we get is an illusion?
Can someone explain this?

Comment: 'exactly 10 seconds after the previous time it was executed' that is sensibly impossible.  You must give a tolerance on the time.  If you want to get as close to 10 seconds as possible, you will need some exta hardware - an array of hydrogen fountain maser clocks, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes it is an illusion. Even with a single threaded program you can make no guarantee that your program will be running at the precise time you want to do an operation. This is because the operating system may have allowed some other task to run at that specific moment. You can use thread priorities to try and encourage the OS scheduler to prioritize your tasks ahead of others, but it is not a guarantee that it will run at a given time.